# Dynamically adding photos to floated left <div> causing footer to jump up to the header

Tags: html, css

```
<div id="page">

    <div id="header">
        Header goes here.
    </div> <!--end of header -->

    <div id="main">

        <div id="photos">
            THIS IS FLOATED LEFT.
            Photos are dynamically added here.
        </div> <!--end of photos-->

    </div><!-- end of main-->

    <div id="footer">
        Footer goes here.
    </div><!-- end of footer -->

</div> <!-- end of page-->
```

In this code I'm trying to add photos dynamically to the div "photo" which is floated LEFT.
Now what happens when I try to add photos is my footer goes up to the header. The div main has a background color. On adding more photos the photos goes out of the main i.e. outside the color content. I've used clear property for the floating element. 
Please, help me understand where am I wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this line

```
<br style="clear: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;" />

</div><!-- end of main-->
<div id="footer">  Footer goes here.  </div>
<!-- end of footer -->    </div> 
<!-- end of page-->
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. It is somewhat working. There are issues but I won't bother you people for such petty problems now. I'll try figuring it out myself. Nonetheless, your help mattered.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is happening because floated elements don't really occupy any vertical space in the page layout (since other elements are allowed to wrap around them). Since the left-floated div "photos" is the only content within the "main" div, the "main" div is treated as if is has no vertical height. This is why the footer appears directly below the header.

To fix this, you have some options:

1. Add other content to the "main" div that is NOT floated
2. Specify a fixed height for the "main" div (not a good solution)
3. Leave the "photos" div unfloated, and float other content in the main div to the right
4. Use clear:right or clear:both in the "photos" div css. This mostly defeats the purpose of the float, though

(other options exist)

Comment: I pretty much know the reason for what is happening and most of what you tried to help with. Actually, since the photos are being added dynamically, every time a photo is added a new div "photo" is added to the div main. I can't leave it un-floated as it will defeat the purpose and the design of the page. I did try a few things you mentioned but without success. Let's hope someone else comes up with a better solution or I am showered with some light of wisdom.